How Do I get Only latest data processed in my sql table
Scenario:
The table contains data inserted over a 7-day window where data from the 11th to the 17th of each month is inserted daily. Sometimes, overlapping data is inserted, and the challenge is to retrieve the latest data for the start_period.
Start_period     ID   Management_unit   business_unit      activity actual_start_date   actual_end_date
2024-04-15T00:00:00.000Z    13be8b33    MU - INZ Group  BU-MB   Break   17-04-2024 23:51:45 17-04-2024 23:59:59
2024-04-12T00:00:00.000Z    13be8b33    MU - INZ Group  BU-MB   Break   17-04-2024 23:51:45 17-04-2024 23:40:59
2024-04-11T00:00:00.000Z    13be8b33    MU - INZ Group  BU-MB   Break   17-04-2024 23:22:45 17-04-2024 23:59:59
2024-04-15T00:00:00.000Z    13be8b33    MU - INZ Group  BU-MB   Break   17-04-2024 00:02:57 17-04-2024 00:24:05


Query:
select distinct
    start_period,
    agent_id,
    MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME,
    BUSINESSUNIT_NAME,
    ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,
    actual_start_date ,
    DATE_PART('epoch_second', TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(ACTUAL_START_DATE)) as Start_offset,
    DATE_PART('epoch_second', TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(ACTUAL_END_DATE)) as end_offset,
    end_offset - Start_offset as actual_offset
from (
    with date_dim as (
        select seq4() as id, 
               row_number() over (order by id) as row_num,
               dateadd(day,row_num,'1999-12-31'::timestamp) as date
        from TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 36500))
    ), 
    data_table as (
        select seq4() as id,
               start_date,
               agent_id,
               BUSINESSUNIT_NAME,
               MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME,
               ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,  
               ACTUAL_START_DATE,
               ACTUAL_END_DATE,
               ACTIVITY_DURATION
        from MYTABLE
    )
    select distinct 
        row_number() over (partition by dt.id order by dd.id) as id,
        dt.start_date as start_period,
        dt.agent_id,
        dt.MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME,
        dt.BUSINESSUNIT_NAME,
        dt.ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,
        case when dt.actual_start_date > dd.date then dt.actual_start_date else dd.date end as actual_start_date,
        case when dt.actual_end_date < dateadd(d,1,dd.date) then dt.actual_end_date else dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(d,1,dd.date)) end as actual_end_date
    from data_table dt
    join date_dim dd
    on dd.date between date_trunc(day,dt.actual_start_date) and dt.actual_end_date
) QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT_ID,MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME,ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,actual_start_date
                          ORDER BY Start_period desc) = 1;



--expectedOutput

| Start_period           | ID      | Management_unit | Business_unit | Activity | Actual_start_date    | Actual_end_date      |
|------------------------|---------|-----------------|---------------|----------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2024-04-15T00:00:00.000Z | 13be8b33 | MU - INZ Group  | BU-MB         | Break    | 17-04-2024 23:51:45  | 17-04-2024 23:59:59  |
| 2024-04-15T00:00:00.000Z | 13be8b33 | MU - INZ Group  | BU-MB         | Break    | 17-04-2024 00:02:57  | 17-04-2024 00:24:05  |


@Mike Walton. is this something you can help?

Hi - is this MySQL or Snowflake, and what do snowflake schemas (which are unrelated to the Snowflake DBMS) have to do with your question? Please edit your tags to those that are relevant to your question. Thanks

Is this a follow-up question leveraging my answer to your previous post that you never accepted as the answer or responded to?

Use a MERGE instead of an insert to avoid adding duplicates
